# How to know if any filter applied in angularjs into controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on spring application with angularjs front end. In my one of the form, I have applied filter using angularjs filters.

I have created text field and applied angularjs filter search on it :

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search.updatedDate" placeholder="Search"/>
<a ng-if="search.updatedDate.length" ng-click="search.updatedDate=''"></a>
```

Many text fields are created for search according to filter in the grid. So I just want to know if any filter is applied in my controller class to work on filtered data.

Comment: Try to put the filter and '$scope.search.updatedDate' variable into a self called function side by side of a variable which will store some value (true/false) after the function is called.
In the end of controller, you can call 'console.log(your_var)' to see if your variable have value true.

Comment: What you should do is to rewrite code, so filtered values will become part of your model.